# Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/library/nginx

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am trying to install Docker on my MAC . I am getting the below issue

```
 predix-docker xxxxxx $ docker pull nginx
 Using default tag: latest
 latest: Pulling from library/nginx
 968c69f18673: Pulling fs layer
 963493e54e68: Layer already being pulled by another client. Waiting.
 755b4eb93a9e: Layer already being pulled by another client. Waiting.
 f3b2532b0301: Layer already being pulled by another client. Waiting.
 f3bf4daa2ff2: Layer already being pulled by another client. Waiting.
6685b2154893: Layer already being pulled by another client. Waiting.
a2295636c7aa: Already exists
3035387b9e83: Already exists
 Pulling repository docker.io/library/nginx
Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/library/nginx
```

When i check for Docker images, i don't find the nginx repo. How to download it please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a local problem on your side:

```
$ docker pull nginx
Using default tag: latest
Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/nginx ... 
latest: Pulling from docker.io/library/nginx

51f5c6a04d83: Already exists 
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete 
51d229e136d0: Pull complete 
bcd41daec8cc: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:0fe6413f3e30fcc5920bc8fa769280975b10b1c26721de956e1428b9e2f29d04
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker.io/nginx:latest
```

Try removing the image (`docker rmi nginx`) and pulling it again.

Also, it looks like you are running concurrent pulls.

Comment: I was behind some proxy so it didn't work for me. Your answer made me understood that .Thanks

Comment: @Warrior I am having a similar problem with a proxy server. How did you get past your problem? I have set the proxy setting the way the documentation says in /etc/sysconfig/docker. Is there something else that needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Docker is handling network errors in a wrong way. E.g. DNS timeout may be reported as "Tag xxx not found". That's why an error may be intermittent. Saw that few times, changing DNS server to google DNS (8.8.8.8) and waiting for few minutes fixed this docker error for me.